# "you had introduced me to him" is it right sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, past-perfect

When I want to say to someone (referred to as B1) that he (B1) introduced me to someone (B2). Can I say

> "You (B1) had introduced me to him (B2)"

Is that a correct sentence?

Say I met a person (B1) in the morning who had introduced me to his colleague (B2). On the same day afternoon when I met B1, I recounted this to him:

> "You had introduced me to B2".

I am doubtful that *"you had introduced me to B2,"* as expressed, was right or wrong.

Comment: Why do you think it would not be correct?  Please add more details like what you are trying to say, and what grammar rules you think should apply to this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply say

> You have **already** introduced us.

if you are standing infront of B2 with B1 about to introduce you.

Or you might say

> B1: Let me introduce you to B2.
>   You: You have **already** introduced me to them.

The "***already***" emphasizes that something has occurred before.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please clarify following doubts? 1.) B1 introduce me to B2 in the morning an I am expressing this information to B1 in the evening. then it becomes past tense. So should I have to say, I had or I have? 2.) apart from the two situations that you had assumed, the third situation and the actual situation was encountered was, B1 didn't attempted introducing B2 again and B2 was not present in front when this was happening in the evening. I just have recount to B1 that he introduced me to B2 and further discussion on what happened after the introduction with B2.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the clause:

> You had introduced me to him

would indicate that it is a preceding statement and  can be followed by the conjuction ***before***
Example:

> You had introduced him to me before he left the meeting.